# Creating Data Clock in ArcGIS Tracking Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, tracking-analyst

I am attempting to create a data clock, under the "Tracking Analyst" toolbar.  I have created a tracking layer, but for some reason the "Create Data Clock" option is grayed out.

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Are you licensed for Tracking Analyst?